# How to Compare the Running Times of Two Data Structures' Operations

Tags: performance, algorithm, data-structures, dataset

I want to compare the performance of two search trees of integers (an AVL tree vs a RedBlack tree). So how should I design/engineer the tests to accomplish this ? For instance, let's consider the *insert* operation, what steps should I follow in order to state that on average this operation is faster in the RB case ? Should I time inserting just one element (assuming the trees are pre-populated) or should I time a sequence of insertions ? Also what considerations should I take to correctly measure CPU time accurately ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really broad question, and as such, I don't think you should be hoping for anybody to get on here and give you the one final correct answer regarding how to measure performance. That being said...

First, you should develop a suite of tests. Two popular techniques exist for doing this: monitor a real-world sequence of operations done by an application (so, find some open source application that uses either an AVL or RB tree, and add some code to print out the sequence of operations it performs) or create such a stream of operations analytically (or synthetically) to target any number of cases (the average usage, particular kinds of abnormal or otherwise unusual usage, random usage, etc.). The more of these kinds of traces you get to test, the better.

Once you have your set of traces to test, you need to develop a driver to do the evaluation. The driver should be simple, the same for both AVL and RB trees (I think that in this case, this shouldn't be a problem; both present the same interface to users, differing only in terms of internal implementation details). The driver should be able to reproduce the usage recorded in your trace sets efficiently and cause the traced operations to be carried out on your data structures. One thing I like to do is to include a third "dummy" candidate that does nothing; this way, I can see how much of an influence the processing of traces is exerting on overall performance.

Each trace should be executed many, many times. You can formalize this somewhat (to reduce statistical uncertainty to within known bounds), but a rule of thumb is that the order of your error will shrink according to 1/sqrt(n), where n is the number of trials. In other words, by running each trace 10,000 times instead of 100 times, you will get errors in the average that are 10x smaller. Record all values; things to look for are the mean, median, mode(s), etc. For each run, try to keep the system conditions the same; no other programs running, etc. To help eliminate spurious results due to external factors changing, you can cull the bottom and top 10% of outliers...

Now, simply compare the data sets. Perhaps what you care most about is the average time the trace takes? Perhaps the worst? Maybe what you really care about is consistency; is the standard deviation big or small? You should have enough data to compare the results for a given trace executed on both test structures; and for different traces, it might make more sense to look at different figures (for instance, if you created a synthetic benchmark that should be the worst case for RB trees, you might ask how badly RB and AVL trees did, whereas you might not care about this for another trace representing the best case for AVL trees, etc.)

Timing on the CPU can be a challenge in its own right. You'll need to ensure that the resolution of your timer is sufficient for measuring your events. clock() and gettimeofday() functions - and others - are popular choices for recording the time of events. If your traces finish too quickly, you can get the aggregate time for several trials (so that if your timer supports microsecond timing and your traces finish in 10 microseconds, you can measure 100 executions of the trace instead of 1, and get time values on 10s of milliseconds, which should be accurate).

Another potential pitfall is providing the same execution environment each time. In between trace runs, at the very least, you might consider techniques for ensuring that you start with a clean cache. Either that, or don't time the first execution, or understand that this result might be culled when you eliminate outliers. It might be safer to just reset the cache (by manipulating every element of some large array, for instance in between executions of traces), since code A might benefit from having some of the values in cache while code B might suffer.

These are a few of the things you might consider when doing your own performance evaluation. Other tools - like PAPI and other profilers, for instance - can measure certain events - cache hits/misses, instructions, etc. - and this information can allow for much richer comparisons than simple comparisons of wall-clock run time.

Comment: Thanks for this extensive answer. Could you provide a link with more information on the cache part? I mean, how does arbitrary code affect the cache and how to code making effective use of the cache. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Measuring CPU time accurately can be very tricky depending on your particular programming language, implementation, etc.  For example, with Java's JIT compilation, the results can be extremely different depending on how much you've run the code before now!

Can you give more detail about your situation?